# How to make each form label unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, label

I don't think what I want to do is possible but I figured I'd ask.
I have the form below that renders the following:

[image]

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @game, assignment ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: "Select Referee" } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to change the label of each assignment so that it doesn't say "name" 5 times and that I could preset the 5 labels with something else. I was thinking of having an array with the predefined labels but I'm not sure how to go about this since the form is essentially a rendition of the same form 5 times instead of one form.

The partial that renders the forms is:

```
<p><%= assignment.id %> | <%= link_to assignment.game_id, game_assignment_path(@game, assignment) %></p>

<p>Edit this assignment:</p>

<%= render "assignments/form", assignment: assignment %>
```

Maybe have a loop around the render statement for each form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you call the partial, do:

```rb
<%= render partial; "assignments/form", locals: {assignment: assignment, label: "My custom label"} %>
```

or if you are rendering the form in a loop you could do something like this:

```rb
<%- @things.each do |thing| %>
  <%= render partial; "assignments/form", locals: {assignment: assignment, label: thing.label } %>
<%- end %>

#or
<%- @things.each_with_index do |thing, index| %>
  <%= render partial; "assignments/form", locals: {assignment: assignment, label: "Member no: #{index+1}" } %>
<%- end %>
```

and in the form:

```rb
<%= form.label :name, label %>
```

Comment: This works but I need each assignment to have a different label. So for example: The first one would say member 1, the second would say member 2...etc

Comment: @wayoh22 you can put a different label for each form that is rendered, if you're  rendering the form partial in a loop, you can embed a loop variable in the label. I'll update my answer to show how